# C# BackgroundWorker Add System.EventHandler to RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, delegates, backgroundworker, eventhandler

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
EventHandler HandleStuff = delegate { MessageBox.Show("HandleStuff called"); };
timer.Tick += HandleStuff;
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += HandleStuff;
```

The last line is not allowed because:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler'

2 questions:
Why can't the RunWorkerCompleted accept a regular EventHandler - the completed event isn't multithreaded, is there a reason this restriction exists?

More importantly, is there a work around to achieve this? I want to use the same handler for `Timer.Tick` and `bw.RunWorkerCompleted`

Comment: 1 ) then replace HandleStuff with something that does except args 

(sender , args ) => { MessageBox ....};

2) the same exact reason .

3) -1

Comment: [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: That msdn page does explain why I can't use a regular event handler (because it needs the handler to accept RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs), however it doesn't address my second question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't the RunWorkerCompleted accept a regular EventHandler?

Because the signature doesn't match the event.  (And the delegate isn't equivalent through co/contra-variance).  The handler *always* needs to be of the same type as the event's delegate, by definition.

> More importantly, is there a work around to achieve this?

You won't be able to attach that exact handler, in terms of that exact reference, no.  The best you can do is create a new event handler of the appropriate type who's body does nothing but call the code that you actually want it to execute:

```
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,args)=> HandleStuff(s,EventArgs.Empty);
```